# Como obtener la ip atreves de http

Tags: php, ip

Hol buenas noches necesito ayuda para poder recuperar las ips de los clientes de mi pagina (php) para poder compararlas en una base de datos.

El problema esta en que hay usuarios que devuelve la ipv4, y otros que devuelve la ipv6.

Yo necesito recuperar en todos los casos, la ipv4.

La pagina pasa por cloudflare para evitar ataques.

Yo he probado varias cosas, sin obtener resultados, los adjunto abajo.

Opción 1:

```
function get_ip_address()
{
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');

    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');

    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');

    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');

    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
       $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');

    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    if (strpos($ipaddress, ",") !== false) :
      $ipaddress = strtok($ipaddress, ",");
    endif;
    return $ipaddress;
}
```

Opción 2:

```
$user_ip = (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])?$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]:$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Opción 3:

```
function ip_in_range($ip, $range) {
   if (strpos($range, '/') == false)
       $range .= '/32';

   // $range is in IP/CIDR format eg 127.0.0.1/24
   list($range, $netmask) = explode('/', $range, 2);
   $range_decimal = ip2long($range);
   $ip_decimal = ip2long($ip);
   $wildcard_decimal = pow(2, (32 - $netmask)) - 1;
   $netmask_decimal = ~ $wildcard_decimal;
   return (($ip_decimal & $netmask_decimal) == ($range_decimal & $netmask_decimal));
}

function _cloudflare_CheckIP($ip) {
   $cf_ips = array(
       '199.27.128.0/21',
       '173.245.48.0/20',
       '103.21.244.0/22',
       '103.22.200.0/22',
       '103.31.4.0/22',
       '141.101.64.0/18',
       '108.162.192.0/18',
       '190.93.240.0/20',
       '188.114.96.0/20',
       '197.234.240.0/22',
       '198.41.128.0/17',
       '162.158.0.0/15',
       '104.16.0.0/12',
   );
   $is_cf_ip = false;
   foreach ($cf_ips as $cf_ip) {
       if (ip_in_range($ip, $cf_ip)) {
           $is_cf_ip = true;
           break;
       }
   } return $is_cf_ip;
}

function _cloudflare_Requests_Check() {
   $flag = true;

   if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']))   $flag = false;
   if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY']))       $flag = false;
   if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_RAY']))             $flag = false;
   if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_VISITOR']))         $flag = false;
   return $flag;
}

function isCloudflare() {
   $ipCheck        = _cloudflare_CheckIP($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
   $requestCheck   = _cloudflare_Requests_Check();
   return ($ipCheck && $requestCheck);
}

// Use when handling ip's
function getRequestIP() {
   $check = isCloudflare();

   if($check) {
       return $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
   } else {
       return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   }
}
```

He probado muchos scrips que esta en internet, pero no me da resultado.

Lo extraño es que si ese cliente entra a una pagina como vermiip.es, le da la ip publica correctamente, y no se como es que la recuperan.

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Las `IPv6` no pueden convertirse a `IPv4`, pero al revés sí.

Comment: si, pero el tema es que no puedo, recuperar la ipv4, ósea me muestra solo la ipv6.

Comment: No vas a poder, lo que intentaba decir es eso. Lo vas a tener que pensar al revés, es decir, si viene `IPv4` convertirla a `v6` o soportar ambas versiones.